# How to run jersey-examples-helloworld-webapp in netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, jersey

I did as oracle documentation said...build and run...but it asked me to select deployment server.

Then I selected glassfish server 4.0(The only choice); however this project couldn't run.

I found it newly created a glassfish-web.xml in folder WEB-INF(the project already had web.xml there before).

I thought may be it just didn't connect the project with the server well.

Comment: When you say the project wouldn't run, what's the error you get?

Comment: SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app
SEVERE:   Undeployment failed for context /helloworld-webapp
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)] @Kerry

Comment: It looks as though you're missing some context or dependency from your project that needs to be injected. Without seeing your code and the full build output it's hard to tell exactly what. Have you added your Glassfish server as a service in netbeans? Also in my experience if you want to learn about Java EE and glassfish the Oracle/sun tutorials are overwhelming. I found the book 'Beginning Java EE with Glassfish 3' very good although it doesn't deal with working with Netbeans.

Comment: Yes, I have added that service. I only use the examples provided by Jersey website. jersey-examples-helloworld can run well, while jersey-examples-helloworld-webapp cannot. The example link is: [link](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.4.1/examples). Also which IDE do you prefer for Jersey restful web service? THX @Kerry

Answer (score 0):

for me it helped to update the pom.xml to omit 2.x compatibility and restart the glassfish domain.
Thanks
Richard

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!--artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId -->
    <!-- use the following if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the jersey-container-servlet-core.jar from the web-inf/lib folder solved this problem for me.